# How to search data in listview with FutureBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I make small app to display listview and then I want can search data into this list view. Now the List is working but the problem into TextField of search. When I click inside TextField the list reload agin and the user out of TextField removed again.

See this image please to understand more the problem:

[image]

As you can see in the image above I can't write data inside TextField.

This is first page I pass list data from this page to second page from FutureBuilder:

```
class firstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<firstPage> {

 
  @override
  void initState() {

 
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kBackground,
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<AllProductModel>>(
                    future: fetchYourProduct(Uids, NameUserContry),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      final ListDataDisplay  = snapshot.data;

                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        default:
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Center(
                                child: Text('Some error occurred!'));
                          } else {
                            return  UserPage(ListDataDisplay:ListDataDisplay);
                          }
                      }
                    },
                  ),


                )
              ],
            ))

        );
  }

}
```

This is second page user page here I display data and I make appBar here also:

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final  ListDataDisplay;
  UserPage({Key? key, required this.ListDataDisplay}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<UserPage> createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {

  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  Widget appBarTitle =  Text('');
  Icon actionIcon =  Icon(
    Icons.search,
    color: CustomColors.firebaseNavy,
  );

  String searchString = "";
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      Scaffold(
          appBar:  AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title:appBarTitle,
              backgroundColor: CustomColors.firebaseGrey,
              elevation: 1.5,
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    if ( this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search){
                      this.actionIcon =  Icon(Icons.close);
                      this.appBarTitle =  TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState((){
                            searchString = value;
                          });

                        },
                        controller: searchController,
                        style:  TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,

                        ),
                        decoration:  InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Name',
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            ),

                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    else {
                      this.actionIcon =  Icon(Icons.search);
                      this.appBarTitle =  Text("List");
                      searchController.clear();
                      searchString='';
                    }

                  }
                  );

                },icon: actionIcon,
                )



                ,]
          ),



          body:

          ListView.builder(

              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.ListDataDisplay.length,

              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return
                  "${widget.ListDataDisplay[index]
                      .name}" ':' "${widget.ListDataDisplay[index].coponId}"
                      .contains(searchString) ?
                  Card(
                    elevation: 1.5,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                       Text(widget.ListDataDisplay[index].name)

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ) : Container();

              }
          )

      );
}
```

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid unecessary reloads for the `Future`, move it into initState so it will load the data once and stored in a variable, then assign that variable to the future property in FutureBuilder like this :

```
late Future someNameHere;
@override
void initState(){
someNameHere = fetchYourProduct(Uids, NameUserContry);
super.initState();
}
```

then in your `FutureBuilder` assign it to future property like :

```
future: someNameHere;
```

Hope it helps